# How can I gets histogram using arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, methods, histogram

Take input from user in an array in form of numeric and show histogram Where i'm     wrong The code is given in java the user can enter 5 input in number and  histogram should show in any form with no constraints

```
package p21;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P21 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   {
    int count[] = new int[10]; // count array will keep elements of element
    // in particular range;
    int elements[]; // for example   27 15 34 22 11 11 19
    { // in above input there is count[0]=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) // count[1]=4 and count[2]=2 and count[3]=1;
     {
      if (elements[i] >= 0 && elements[i] < 50) {
       if (elements[i] < 10) {
        count[0]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 10 && elements[i] < 20) {
        count[1]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 20 && elements[i] < 30) {
        count[2]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 30 && elements[i] < 40) {
        count[3]++;}
        else {
        count[4]++;
       }}
       else if (elements[i] >= 50 && elements[i] <= 100) {
       if (elements[i] < 60) {
        count[5]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 60 && elements[i] < 70) {
        count[6]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 70 && elements[i] < 80) {
        count[7]++;}
        else if (elements[i] >= 80 && elements[i] < 90) {
        count[8]++;}
        else {
        count[9]++;

      }}}}

     {
     System.out.println("Histogram of the elements:");
     for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) // this loop will print line
     {
      for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++) // this will print elements element(*)
      { // at each line.
       System.out.print("* ");
      }
      if (count[i] != 0) // if line does'nt contain zero   
       System.out.println(""); // then if will change the row;
     }
    }
   }
   /*
   in above code if count[i]=zero means if there is elements
   element in particular range say [0-9] then it will
   elementst jump on next line;
   */
   {
    {
     Histogram hg = new Histogram();
     System.out.println("Enter the elements of Elements want in a  Histogram:");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     int noOfElements = sc.nextInt();
     int histogramElements[] = new int[noOfElements];

     System.out.println("Enter the Elements for Histogram:");
     for (int i = 0; i < noOfElements; i++) {
      histogramElements[i] = sc.nextInt();
     }

     hg.showHistogram(histogramElements);
    }
```

Comment: ..didn't you just ask a similar question ? please edit the code formatting and specify where exactly you are having a problem. As it is now, the code does not even compile because of the braces..

Comment: hot hell your braces and alignment are totally weird

Comment: Question can be similar but code are different ......

Comment: @RajpootRajpoot Please fix your braces and realign your code. If you want someone to dedicate their time to help you fix your problem, you should at least be putting in the effort to write a good question and make your code understandable

Comment: Fixed your disastrous braces with a formatter though the indenting needs some work. Please don't post unreadable code. It's much harder to help you.

Comment: Tip about braces - you don't need braces after every statement, and you don't need two braces after a loop/class declaration (see the 2 braces after your public static void main declaration).

Comment: @tnw thanks. It's still disastrous because of how he has opening braces not after loops or method declarations but before statements like System.out.print, like when he prints out "Histogram of the Elements"

Comment: ragingasinancoder now?

Comment: @RajpootRajpoot .. does your code compile ? There are missing & extra braces all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

For your binning approach.....  since you only care about groups of 10. Divide the input number by 10.   Bound the divided result then use the result to index your counter array.

Comment: Do you have any histogram algorithm?.Why you don't try to correct my code.